# список смежности ориентированного графа

Tags: python, графы, олимпиада, graph

Дана олимпиадная задача по информатике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача A. Город перекрёстков**
Вы разрабатываете навигатор для одного города. Этот город разбит улицами на квадратные кварталы, причём движение по любому из отрезков улицы в пределах каждого квартала строго одностороннее. С каждого перекрёстка можно выехать только в разрешённых знаками направлениях. Требуется по прилагаемой карте города с указанными на ней разрешёнными направлениями перемещения проложить самый короткий маршрут из точки AA в точку BB.

**Формат входных данных**

На вход подаётся карта перекрёстков города. В первой строке содержатся два числа NN  — число кварталов с севера на юг и MM — число кварталов с запада на восток (1 ≤ n ≤ 50). Точка AA самая северо-западная, точка BB самая юго-восточная. Далее в 2*N+12∗N+1 строках содержится описание разрешённых направлений движения. Улицы города запад-восток описаны в нечётных строках. В каждой такой строке содержится по MM символов без пробела, указывающих разрешённое движение на соответствующем участке. В чётных строках содержится описание улиц север-юг. В этих строках содержится по M+1M+1 символов, указывающих возможное движение по отрезкам улиц север-юг. Движение на север, юг, запад, восток обозначается буквами n, s, w, e  соответственно.

**Формат выходных данных**

В первую строку вывести число отрезков улиц в самом коротком маршруте из точки AA в точку BB. Во вторую строку нужно выдать описание этого маршрута в виде последовательности символов n, s, w, e без пробелов. Если кратчайших маршрутов несколько, выдать самый первый среди них по алфавитному порядку. Гарантируется, что из точки AA можно попасть в точку BB.

**Пояснение к первому примеру**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Sample Input 1:**

```
4 5
weeee
snssss
wewww
snsnns
weeew
snnsns
wwwew
ssssns
eeeew
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
29
sssseeeennnwwseswwnnneeeessss
```

**Sample Input 2:**

```
2 2
ee
sss
ee
sss
ee
```

**Sample Output 2:**

```
4
eess
```

Первое, что пришло мне в голову, - это создать списки смежности ориентированного графа:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())

west_east = []
north_south = []

for i in range(1, 2 * n + 2):
   if i % 2 != 0:
       west_east.append(input())
   else:
       north_south.append(input())

graphs = []
for i in range((n+1)*(m+1)):
   graphs.append([])
   if west_east[i % (n + 1)][(i - 1) % m] == 'w' and i - 1 >= 0:
       graphs[i].append(i - 1)
   elif i % (m + 1) != m:
       graphs[i].append(i + 1)

   if north_south[(i - 1) % n][i % (m + 1)] == 'n' and i - (m + 1) >= 0:
       graphs[i].append(i - (m + 1))
   elif i + m + 1 < 9:
       graphs[i].append(i + (m + 1))


print(west_east)
print(north_south)
print(graphs)
```

Однако мой код работает не совсем правильно. Он выдает, допустим, для нулевой вершины 1 и 6, когда он должен выдавать 6, так как путь из 0 ведет только туда. Помогите разобраться, я запутался(((

Comment: У вас задан неявный граф из ~N*M вершин и ~2*N*M ребер. Кратчайший путь в невзвешенном графе ищется простым поиском в ширину. Если вас смущает, что граф задан в неявном виде, то перезадайте его в явном.

Comment: @EzikBro, а как это сделать? я просто в теории графов не так много знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что у меня получилось и это вроде-бы работает

```
n, m = [int(i) for i in str(input()).split()]
points = []
for i in range(n + 1):
    k = []
    for j in range(m + 1):
        k.append(str(i) + '_' + str(j))
    points.append(k)
k = []
for i in points:
    for j in i:
        k.append(j)
napr = []
for i in range(n):
    napr.append([str(input()) + '-', str(input())])
napr.append([str(input())])
pointsnap = points.copy()
for i in range(len(pointsnap)):
    for j in range(len(pointsnap[i])):
        pointsnap[i][j] = []
for i in range(len(napr)):
    for j in range(len(napr[i][-1])):
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
        elif i == 0 and j != 0 and j < len(napr[0][-1]) - 1:
            if j - 1 >= 0:
                if napr[i][0][j - 1] == 'w':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('w')
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
        elif i == 0 and j == len(napr[0][0]) - 1:
            if j - 1 >= 0:
                if napr[i][0][j - 1] == 'w':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('w')
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
        elif i != 0 and i < len(napr) - 1 and j == 0:
            if napr[i - 1][-1][j] == 'n':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('n')
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
        elif i == len(napr) - 1 and j == 0:
            if (i - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i - 1][-1][j] == 'n':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('n')
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
        elif i != 0 and i < len(napr) - 1 and j != 0 and j < len(napr[0][-1]) - 1:
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
            if (i - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i - 1][-1][j] == 'n':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('n')
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
            if (j - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i][0][j - 1] == 'w':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('w')
        elif i == (len(napr) - 1) and j != 0:
            if napr[i][0][j] == 'e':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('e')
            if (j - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i][0][j - 1] == 'w':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('w')
            if (i - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i - 1][-1][j] == 'n':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('n')
        elif i != 0 and j == (len(napr[0][0]) - 1):
            if napr[i][-1][j] == 's':
                pointsnap[i][j].append('s')
            if (i - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i - 1][-1][j] == 'n':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('n')
            if (j - 1) >= 0:
                if napr[i][-1][j - 1] == 'w':
                    pointsnap[i][j].append('w')
count = 0
for i in range(len(pointsnap)):
    for j in range(len(pointsnap[i])):
        pointsnap[i][j].append(str(count))
        count += 1
con = dict()
for i in range(len(points)):
    for j in range(len(points[i])):
        d = []
        for h in pointsnap[i][j]:
            if h == 'e':
                d.append(pointsnap[i][j + 1][-1])
            elif h == 's':
                d.append(pointsnap[i + 1][j][-1])
            elif h == 'w':
                d.append(pointsnap[i][j - 1][-1])
            elif h == 'n':
                d.append(pointsnap[i - 1][j][-1])
        con[pointsnap[i][j][-1]] = d



def bfs(graph_to_search, start, end):
    queue = [[start]]
    visited = set()

    while queue:

        path = queue.pop(0)

        vertex = path[-1]

        if vertex == end:
            return path
        elif vertex not in visited:
            for current_neighbour in graph_to_search.get(vertex, []):
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(current_neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

            visited.add(vertex)


path = [int(i) for i in bfs(con, '0', str(count - 1))]
print(len(path) - 1)
path2 = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(pointsnap)):
    for j in range(len(pointsnap[i])):
        pointsnap[i][j] = count
        count += 1
row = 0
column = 0
for i in path[1:]:
    if i in pointsnap[row]:
        if i < pointsnap[row][column]:
            path2.append('w')
            column -= 1
        else:
            path2.append('e')
            column += 1
    else:
        if (row - 1) >= 0 and i in pointsnap[row - 1]:
            path2.append('n')
            row -= 1
        else:
            path2.append('s')
            row += 1
print(''.join(path2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())

west_east = []
north_south = []

for i in range(1, 2 * n + 2):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        west_east.append(input())
    else:
        north_south.append(input())

graphs = [[] for i in range((n + 1) * (m + 1))]
for i in range((n + 1) * (m + 1)):
    if west_east[i % (n + 1)][(i - 1) % m] == 'w' and (i - 1) % m + 1 == i:
        if i - 1 not in graphs[i]:
            graphs[i].append(i - 1)
    elif west_east[i % (n + 1)][(i - 1) % m] == 'w' and (i - 1) % m - 1 == i:
        if i - 1 not in graphs[i]:
            graphs[i + 1].append(i)
    elif west_east[i % (n + 1)][(i - 1) % m] == 'e' and (i - 1) % m - 1 == i:
        if i + 1 not in graphs[i]:
            graphs[i].append(i + 1)
    elif west_east[i % (n + 1)][(i - 1) % m] == 'e' and (i - 1) % m + 1 == i:
        if i + 1 not in graphs[i - 1]:
            graphs[i - 1].append(i)

    if north_south[(i - 1) % n][i % (m + 1)] == 'n' and i - (m + 1) >= 0:
        graphs[i].append(i - (m + 1))
    elif i + m + 1 < 9:
        graphs[i].append(i + (m + 1))

print(west_east)
print(north_south)
print(graphs)
```